# how to redirect url request to https in webforms proj

Tags: c#, http, https

Any thoughts on why implementing Application_BeginRequest to check for the Url scheme (to replace http with https within the requested url and redirect) coupled with

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

in the config file of a webforms solution is not enough to achieve this purpose?
So far it works only for urls like: www.mysite.com/path1, not for www.mysite.com/path1/file.aspx. here it says it didn't find the file. How can i force it to switch to https *before* actually looking for a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do redirects on global.asax file on Application_BeginRequest()
This is one of the ways you can go about it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i had already tried that. There must be sth overriding this behaviour somewhere